# Of these three methods, which is the best one to implement a voting system?

Tags: javascript

I'm implementing a small voting system on my website. I came up with three implementation methods that I would like your feedback on.

I want to give my users the ability to cast several types of votes on some user generated content. It's micro Q&A about games, not unlike SO's and their vote system, on a much smaller and specialized scale.

After toying with the following methods I can't decide which is best.

**Method 1:** Uses URL params and forms

**Method 2:** Uses URL params and jQuery

**Method 3:** Uses ether one of the above, but retrieves its info from the database

The schema assumes both Q's and A's are a post object with a different postTypeId, and the following two tables:

```
voteTypes(id, voteTypeId, voteName) 
votes(id, postId, parentId, userId, ownerUserId, voteTypeId)
```

> 1. parentId represents the id of the
>      parent post. If the post being voted
>      on is an answer post, it is used to
>      ensure a question post (postTypeId=1)
>      can have only one accepted answer.
> 2. ownerUserId represents the userId of
>      the post's (being vote on) owner. It
>      is compared against the userId, which
>      comes from the session, to ensure a
>      user can't vote on his or her own
>      posts.
> 3. userId comes from the session and represents the person casting the
>      vote.

---

**Method 1** Create a vote form in the view as the query loops over each post. Use hidden fields to capture the data:

```
<input type="hidden" value="@voteTypeId" etc...
```

The postId, parentId, and ownerUserId will come from the query being output to the view. The userId will come from the session.

**Disadvantages:**
1. Users can manipulate data. A user can accept an answer to a question he did not ask since ownerUserId is set at the view level.
2. Cumbersome: I would have to create as many forms as there are posts in the view. Each post will have 4 forms. A page with 10 posts can have 40 forms.

**Advantages:**
1. It's simple.

---

**Method 2** Use anchors with custom data tags and jQuery to construct the vote URL.

```
<a data-vote-type-id="@voteTypeId" data-post-id="@postId" etc...
```

The ownerUserId, postId, parentId, voteTypeId will come from the URL. The userId from the session.

**Advantages** 
1. Light weight and no forms. One jQuery call to submit any vote, as such: 
`var data = 'voteTypeId='$(this).data("vote-type-id")` etc. Submitted over ajax!

**Disadvantages:** 
1. JS disabled = no vote. 
2. Data can be manipulated since it's being sent through the URL.

---

**Method 3** Submit only the voteTypeId and the postId over URL, using either methods 1 or 2. Use the postId to query the db and verify the post object being voted on exists. This way I can also verify the ownerUserId and parentId of the post.

If the post is an object, create a newVote object.

The userId will come from the session. The postId and voteTypeId will come from the URL. 
The parentId and ownerUserId will come from the post object I queried for.

**Advantages:** 
1. Data shielded from user manipulation as the presence of the post can be verified, and so can be it's ownerUserId and parentId.

**Disadvantages:** 
1. Laborious. Asking the database to find the post and retrieve details already available at the view level seems unnecessary. 
2. The data is denormalized in some instances, so after a successful vote (an up vote, for example) I have to increment the posts table via object callbacks (add +1 to the existing number of up votes, for example), which is yet another call to the database with information that was already available at the view, and then the controller levels.

---

Other things I have not considered: 
1. Finding if a vote already exists and toggling it, which will require yet another query. 2. Validation combinations are a nightmare.

I'm looking for feedback or additional ideas. So please share!
Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with Method 2, but with some changes.

### Server side

Hooks for casting a vote, changing a vote etc. those return simply `true` or `false` depending on the success.
Input PostID, VoteTypeID, UserID etc. you **can't** leave this out, if this is your bottleneck rethink the database model (if you can't fit it into a relational DB use noSQL stuff).

If you leave validation out, **I'm gonna personally down rank your site into oblivion**, do server side validation.
***ALWAYS***.

### Client side

The Client gets the information from the view, then it can issue the specific calls to the server, we assume a non-malicious user here, if that's not the case he will simply fail at the back end.

As soon as someone casts/toggles we do the following things:

1. Check whether this action is possible by using the data available in the view
2. Update the UI to reflect the change
3. Send the request to the server
4. If that request returns `false` we undo the action and give an error message

**Benefits of this approach:**

1. Security, I can't do impossible things just by sending some http requests
2. Users get a fast response and a decent feedback on errors
3. Since errors are unlikely to occur for non-malicious users we don't need endless amounts of checks here
4. Malicious users, well there fault if the UI fails, we don't care out backend is secure.

Comment: many thanks for your input. The issue becomes this: If I use method two and modify it as you suggested, it really becomes method three. In order to validate the information server side, the posts table will have to be pinged to get the ownerUserId, and the parentId of the post. Validating the presence of the data is not the difficult part here; rather, ensuring that it's accurate. For example, unless I make a request to the posts table to verify the ID of the owner, there is no way to tell if the current person casting an "accept" vote is actually the real owner. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Mel Well there's no way around that. What do you expect a magical unicorn that tells you whether it's the correct owner? Also, don't you think that accepting and voting will be a rather small hit compared to all the requests you need to make in order to render it? Well yes you can cache that to a certain degree, but still DB should not be your problem here, it works for SO, so I don't think that your rather small site will run into problems.

Comment: Thanks, Ivo. I'll go along with your suggestion. It just felt unnatural to query the database again in order to validate something.